# Populate date based on certain criteria

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

Let's say I have a date in cell A1 in excel 24/05/2023 13:45.
I want the date to be populated in B1 based on following criteria,
If time is >17:00, then B1 should be Next Day with time as 09:00 and If Day in A1 is a Friday / Saturday / Sunday then B1 should be next working day with same time as A1

Hoping to get the formula.

Tried to compare the weekend and date function separately, but unable to club both the functions.

Comment: What if it's Friday after 17:00? Should it evaluate as Monday 17:00 or 9:00 in cell B1?

Comment: Hello Mark, If it is Friday after 17:00 then it should evaluate as 17:00 in cell B1

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(A1,15)<4,
    A1+4-WEEKDAY(A1,15),
    IF(MOD(A1,1)>17/24,INT(A1)+33/24,A1))
```

[image]

1. The WEEKDAY function's `return_type` argument is set to `15` so `{1,2,3,4}` is returned for `{Fri,Sat,Sun,Mon}`.  For all numbers `n` returned by the WEEKDAY function, where `n<4`, it is always the case that `WEEKDAY(date+(4-n))=4` (Monday).
2. For all other days, `NOT(n<4)` , the time is retrieved using the MOD function to get the fraction portion of the date.  `MOD(num, 1)` is equivalent to `num-INT(num)` .

   - If the time is greater than `17/24` , 5:00 PM, then the INT function is used to discard the time, and `33/24` , 1 day and 9 hours, is added to the integer.
   - If the time is not greater than `17/24` , then the original date is returned (unchanged).

##### Array Formula

1. The same formula can also be adapted using [BYROW](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/byrow-function-2e04c677-78c8-4e6b-8c10-a4602f2602bb) to map an array of values into a [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) function which will apply its formula to each row using the arbitrarily named variable `r` to represent the current row in the formula.
2. The [LEN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/len-lenb-functions-29236f94-cedc-429d-affd-b5e33d2c67cb) function is used identify rows without values `IF(LEN(r)>0`

```
=BYROW(A:A,LAMBDA(r, IF(LEN(r)>0,
   IF(WEEKDAY(r,15)<4,
      r+4-WEEKDAY(r,15),
      IF(MOD(r,1)>17/24,
         INT(r)+33/24,r)),"")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think it suits the requirement. I will revert if any further help is needed.